# Proof verification: Continuity of $\int^x_{-\infty} f$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to solve the following problem in Royden's Real Analysis 3e: Let $f$ be a non-negative Lebesgue measurable function such that $\int f <\infty$. Show that $F(x) = \int^x_{-\infty}f$ is continuous by using the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

The Monotone Convergence Theorem states that given an increasing sequence $(f_n)$ of non-negative Lebesgue measurable functions with $f = \lim f_n$ almost everywhere, we have $\int f = \lim \int f_n$.

But I also see that we have the following proposition: Let $f$ be a non-negative measurable function. If $\int f<\infty$, then given $\varepsilon >0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for every set $A\subset E$ with $mA<\delta$ we have $\int_A f<\varepsilon$.

So to show $F$ is continuous, we first need to show $\lim_{t\downarrow x}F(t) = F(x)$. To do so, we simply note that $F(t)-F(x) = \int^t_x f$ and invoke the above proposition.
To show $\lim_{t\uparrow x}F(t) = F(x)$, given $x\in \mathbb R$, we define the sequence $f_n(t) = f(t)$ if $t\in (-\infty,x-\frac{1}{n})$ and 0 otherwise. Hence $f_n \to f$ monotonically on $(-\infty,x)$, and using the Monotone Convergence Theorem, we find $\lim \int_{-\infty}^{x-1/n} f = \lim \int_{-\infty}^x f_n = \int_{-\infty}^x f$, that is, $\lim_{t\uparrow x}F(t) = F(x)$.

Is my argument correct? If so, couldn't we have also used the stated proposition to show $\lim_{t\downarrow x} F(t) = F(x)$? Of course the proof of the proposition relies on the Monotone Convergence Theorem, so in some sense we would have used the MCT, but I doubt this is what Royden had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument that $\lim_{t\downarrow x}F(t) = F(x)$ is wrong.